# changing cursor from outside the form class in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, cursor

I have a function inside a module in which I need to change the cursor
I know that in order to change a cursor we can use `Me.Cursor=Cursors.cursor_name`
however since the function is within a module and not the form class, I cannot access `Me`

What can I use instead?

P.S.:*the function is used so many times it is impractical to write this line (twice) for each call*

Edit:
P.S.2: the function is also used in almost each form so I cannot use the name of the form neither

Comment: Use the name of the form variable. That's all Me is; a shortcut to refer to the object within itself.

Comment: @andrewBarber I cannot cause the function is used in each form (check my edit)

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem. You need to know the references to your forms somewhere.

Comment: @andrewBarber yes that could be a way, I'll try to implement it. except if I could find a simpler solution

Comment: I'm almost certain there is a simpler way, but you've not given enough information to know what would work best in your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: sending Me in the parameters of the function as form:

```
Public Function search(byVal myForm as Form,...(my other parameters)) As DataTable
    myform.Cursor=Cursors.WaitCursor
    ' do the function work
    myform.Cursor=Cursors.Default
End Function
```

and calling it as such:

```
search(Me,...)
```

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Not really nice, but I think there's no better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is rather old question but I was searching for a solution and found:

```
Form.ActiveForm
```

which could be used here if the form to change the cursor is active form (this seems to be pretty obvious).